# Keep container up in the pod - kubenetes

Tags: kubernetes

One of the container in the pod is going down. To debug, i have to be able to login to the container which is going down.

In docker, we had an option to use below

docker run -d  sleep infinity

But what about kubenetes? The container is one of the 3 containers in the POD. How can i bring it up and use sleep infinity or anything similar.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same. Make the command of the container sleep infinity and then exec into it.

You can do the same in serval ways.

1. Edit the yaml manifest and apply.
2. Use `kubectl edit <deployment-name>` on the deployment resource in your cluster.
3. Use `kubectl patch` on the deployment resource in your cluster.

You can exec into the specifc container by using the `--container` or short `-c` flag.

```
kubectl exec <pod> --container <container> -ti -- sh
```

Comment: Thank you. Just to be clear you are asking to edit the deployment and just add sleep infinity for the container in the deployment right ?

Comment: @WebDeveloper2017, yes the deployment or whatever controlls the pod. If its just a pod without controller, then edit the pod directly.